# why LinkedIn version20.30.4 doesn't work for finding organizations by vanity name?

Tags: linkedin-api

I’m trying to migrate the LinkedIn version from 202301 to 202311 and I have a problem with the “Find Organization by Vanity Name“ endpoint . I use the vanity endpoint for mentioning LinkedIn Companies, but I receive "Not enough permissions to access: organizations.FINDER-vanityName.20231101". From the documentation, I saw that the compliances permission is needed now? Is this permission mandatory for this endpoint or I'm doing something wrong in postman?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2023-11&tabs=http

postman-vanity-name

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2023-11&tabs=http

postman-vanity-name

LinkedIn